# How to turn off icloud when no account has been set up by me

Tags: icloud

I updated my Phone 5S with ios8 mostly just to get rid of the Notification on my Settings Icon. Now every time I open the phone to use it I am asked to enter my iCloud password (yes, same as iTunes) and yet I have never established an iCloud account.

I can't find anything to help me to get rid of the bloody reminder. Help

Comment: if you have an iTunes account you have an iCloud accout

Answer (score -1):

Well i found an easy solution for your problem.You can remove your iCloud account with this tool.The most important think is:your device must be legit(not stolen or declared as lost by another person).It takes you 3-4 minutes and is done.Then you can setup another iCloud or leave it empty.Click this link 
=> [bypass icloud activation](http://bypassios7activationlock.info)

Comment: If I have seen scam this one smells of it!